# Наследование классов PHP [private vs protected and public]

Tags: php, ооп

Не знаю как в данном случае написать заголовок, но собственно в чем вопрос?

**Смотрим код:**

```
<?php
class People
{
    private function status() {return __METHOD__;}
    public function Sleep(){
        echo $this->status().'<br />';
    }
}
class Programmer extends People
{
    private function status() {return __METHOD__;}
}
$obj = new Programmer();
$obj->Sleep();
?>
```

**На выходе следующее** `People::status`

В этом примере меняем модификаторы доступа на **protected** (или **public** результат в итоге будет тот что и у **protected**)

```
<?php
class People
{
    protected function status() {return __METHOD__;}
    public function Sleep(){
        echo $this->status().'<br />';
    }
}
class Programmer extends People
{
    protected function status() {return __METHOD__;}
}
$obj = new Programmer();
$obj->Sleep();
?>
```

**На выходе следующее** `Programmer::status`

Как работает данный механизм?
Не понятно почему с **private** он не выдает тот же результат что и с **protected**. На сайте **php.net** я такого не увидел (там что-то вскользь упомянуто про закрытые методы, но этой информации недостаточно для понимания)

Comment: На php.net всё про данную ситуацию есть (читать по порядку):

- [область видимости](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php);
- [позднее статическое связывание](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Comment: @uorypm я все это по несколько раз читал, и я понимаю как работает область видимости и позднее статическое связывание, тут проблема в другом...внимательнее присмотрись

Comment: так расскажите в чем проблема, если не в вашем непониманием области видимости?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оформлю свой коммент в виде ответа.
В документации о вашей ситуации написано:

- [Область видимости](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php)
- [Позднее статическое связывание](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

  ```
  <?php

  class People
  {
      private function status()
      {
          return __METHOD__;
      }

      public function sleep()
      {
          echo static::status().'<br />';
      }
  }

  class Programmer extends People
  {
      private function status()
      {
          return __METHOD__;
      }
  }

  $obj = new Programmer();
  $obj->sleep();
  ```

Обратите особое внимание на описание ошибки:

> FATAL ERROR Call to private method Programmer::status() ***from context
>   'People'*** on line number 12

Comment: Я немного "завтыкал", я понял свой промах (что забавное копал совсем не там где надо) =)

Answer (score 2):

Закрытые (приватные) методы доступны только изнутри класса. Когда Вы создаете в наследнике новый приватный метод `Programmer::status()`, Вы не переопределяете родительский метод, а действительно пишите новую функцию с таким же именем, как и функция в родителе, но только в другой области видимости. Т.к. у Вас в наследнике не переопределен метод `Sleep()`, то когда Вы делаете вызов:

```
$obj = new Programmer();
$obj->Sleep();
```

`Programmer::Sleep()` исполняется как `parent::Sleep()`. А в области видимости `parent` метод `status()` определен и должен вернуть People::status. Т.е. если бы Вы переопределили бы метод `Programmer::Sleep()`, результат был бы такой же как при смене модификаторов доступа, потому что в данном случае код вызывал бы метод `Sleep()` из своей области видимости.

```
<?php
class Programmer extends People
{
    private function status() {return __METHOD__;}
    public function Sleep(){
        echo $this->status().'<br />';
    }
}
```

На выходе получим: `Programmer::status`.

Не объявляйте закрытыми методы, реализацию которых Вы хотите изменить в наследниках. Специально для этого есть модификатор доступа `protected`, такие методы будут доступны для всей иерархии наследования.

Comment: я понимал что private метод в programmer не переопределял (не существует же понятие переопределения для private чего либо)
я не понял одного: как получилось, что область видимости в наследнике стала другой т.e как метод Sleep из родительского класса не увидел приватный метод который я объявил?

Comment: потому что вызов `Programmer::Sleep()` в вашем случае эквивалентен вызову из класса Programmer `parent::Sleep()`, область видимости `parent::` - это класс People, соответсвенно вполне естественно, что в итоге происходит вызов `People::status()`. Еще раз: область видимости класса People - это класс People, не Programmer; если вы не переопределили метод Sleep() в Programmer, то происходит вызов `parent::Sleep()` (`People::Sleep()`) , для которого в `$this->status()` $this - это указатель на объект класса People.

Comment: Может стоит отметить ответ, как решение?) Всё подробно разжевали же.